# how to update column with type 'double' in database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i've been trying to update one column that stores data type double in it, but it failed without any error and i have no idea what i do wrong

i tried using both rawquery and update using ContentValues but both doesn't work, i know it's related to REAL data type in sqlite but i have no idea how to make it work

my table

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_WOUND
            = "CREATE TABLE "
            + WOUND_TABLE_NAME + "("
            //+ WOUND_ID + " TEXT,"
            + WOUND_POSITION + " INT,"
            + WOUND_SIZE + " DOUBLE,"
            + WOUND_OWNER + " TEXT,"
            + WOUND_PHOTO + " TEXT,"
            + WOUND_THUMBNAIL + " TEXT,"
            + WOUND_TREATED + " INT DEFAULT 0,"
            + WOUND_NUMBER + " INT,"
            + WOUND_DATE + " INT,"
            +" FOREIGN KEY ("+WOUND_OWNER+") REFERENCES "+PATIENT_TABLE_NAME+"("+PATIENT_ID+"),"
            +" FOREIGN KEY ("+WOUND_POSITION+") REFERENCES "+WOUND_POSITION_TABLE_NAME+"("+POSITION_NUMBER+"),"
            +" PRIMARY KEY ("+ WOUND_OWNER +", "+ WOUND_POSITION +", "+ WOUND_NUMBER +", "+ WOUND_DATE +")"
            + ")";
```

this is my update function

```
public boolean setWoundSizeValue(String ownerID,String position,String number,long date,Double value){
        boolean setSuccess = false;

        /*approach 2
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(WOUND_SIZE,value);*/
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            /*approach 1, didn't work
        try{
            String strSQL = "UPDATE "+WOUND_TABLE_NAME+" SET "+WOUND_SIZE+" = "+value+" WHERE "+WOUND_OWNER+" = "+ownerID+" AND "
                    + WOUND_POSITION+" = "+position+ " AND "+ WOUND_NUMBER +" = "+ number +" AND "+WOUND_DATE +" = "+date;
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(strSQL,null);
            if(c!=null){
                if(c.moveToFirst()){
                    setSuccess = true;
                }
                c.close();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
        }*/


           /*approach 2 didn't work
            long result = db.update(WOUND_TABLE_NAME,cv,WOUND_OWNER+"=? AND "+ WOUND_POSITION+"=? AND "+ WOUND_NUMBER +"=? AND "+WOUND_DATE+"=?"
            ,new String[]{ownerID,position,number,String.valueOf(date)});
            if(result>0){
                setSuccess = true;
            }*/

        return setSuccess;

    }
```

and this is where i call my update function

```
public class SetWoundSizeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText setWoundSize;
    private Button saveButton;
    private String owner;
    private String position;
    private String woundNum;
    private String timer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_wound_size);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Set Wound Size");

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        owner = intent.getStringExtra("owner");
        position = intent.getStringExtra("position");
        woundNum = intent.getStringExtra("woundNum");
        timer = intent.getStringExtra("timer");

        setWoundSize = findViewById(R.id.wound_size);
        saveButton = findViewById(R.id.wound_size_button);

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(SetWoundSizeActivity.this);
                SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                final double woundSize = Double.valueOf(setWoundSize.getText().toString());
                Toast.makeText(SetWoundSizeActivity.this,"size is"+woundSize,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //String ownerID,String position,String number,long date,float value
                boolean result;
                result = helper.setWoundSizeValue(owner,position,woundNum,Long.valueOf(timer),woundSize);
                if(result){
                    Toast.makeText(SetWoundSizeActivity.this,"size inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{Toast.makeText(SetWoundSizeActivity.this,"size not inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

there is no error but the result confirming in where i call it is always false

Answer (score 0):

`rawQuery()` does not work for sure because it is only used to fetch data in the form of a `Cursor`.
But [`update()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#update(java.lang.String,%2520android.content.ContentValues,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String%5B%5D)) with `ContentValues` does work and it is the recommended way:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(WOUND_SIZE, value);
int rows = db.update(
  WOUND_TABLE_NAME, 
  cv,
  WOUND_OWNER + " = ? AND " + WOUND_POSITION + " = ? AND " + WOUND_NUMBER + " = ? AND " + WOUND_DATE + " = ?",
  new String[] {ownerID, position, number, String.valueOf(date)}
);
```

In the variable `rows` will be returned the number of rows updated.

Comment: exactly what i've tried before, it did not update as i checked rows>0 return true; the boolean result is false...

Comment: If rows>0 returned true then this means that it did update.

Comment: no, i mean i did make a condition like that but the result = helper.setWoundSizeValue(...) return false

Comment: Did you debug to check the return value of update() immediately after it is finished? setWoundSizeValue() is a cover method and maybe the value returned is not correct. Also is there a case that the row that you want to update with all these conditions in the WHERE clause does exist. If it exists update() will update it. You can be sure about that. First check the value returned from update().

Comment: check the value of setSuccess with these lines

if (rows>0){
            setSuccess = true;
        }
        Log.d("MYUPDATE"," the result is "+setSuccess);
        return setSuccess;
it says 
com.example.woundtreatment D/MYUPDATE:  the result is false

Comment: Are you sure that the row you try to update exists in the table? Did you run a rawQuery() to fetch it successfully?

Comment: it does exist, i can confirm that

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. Extract the database from the device. Inspect the table for any inconsistencies.